# How can I make a boxplot for each row of df?

Tags: python, dataframe, row, boxplot

I have some data, it looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'in1' : [100, 150, 110, 180, 125], 
                   'in2' : [200, 210, 125, 125, 293],
                   'in3' : [50, 35, 200, 100, 180]
                   'a' : [c, d, e, f,g]})
```

How can I make a boxplot per row of in1 to in3?

Comment: Sorry, your edit to the question confuses me. Could you elaborate a bit more? How many boxes do you want to see? How is the column `a` supposed to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply type this:

```py
df.T.boxplot()
```

The `pandas.DataFrame.boxplot`-method creates a box for each column. You can work around this by using the `pandas.DataFrame.T`-method which transposes the dataframe (i.e., rows become columns and vice versa).